# trouble in prediction in neural network classifier

Tags: classification, matlab, neural-networks

I am training a 4-class neural network classifier. 
The details of my data are:

featurelength = 280

```
              training      testing
---------------------------------------------
no. samples      438           250
samples class1   203           135
samples class2   19            10
samples class3   16             5
samples class4   200           100
```

After I train the neural network.

The confusion matrices are as follows:

```
203 0 0 0 
19  0 0 0
16  0 0 0
200 0 0 0
```

Similarly for test data too.
All the data is predicted to be of class 1.

How can I debug this issue? What is the reason behind such performance?
In addition to this, no. of samples for class 2 and class 3 are very less. How can I make sure that they are not dominated?

Comment: my first bet is that the labelling is wrong. are you sure all samples are correctly labelled when you feed them into the classifier?

Comment: I think so. But let me check again.

Comment: @juampa, data seems alright. funny thing is I added some more data of class 4 in training, and the no. of samples in class 4 is now 300. With this, I get good results in training. Test result is not so good though. But why so?  AccTrain: 0.814126
AccTest: 0.566581

Mean Diag train: 0.894766
Mean Diag test: 0.416521
Confusion matrix training:
  [ 148     0     0    55;
     0    19     0     0;
     0     0    16     0;
    44     0     1   255]

Comment: Right now I cannot figure out what your problem could be. I do not know the matlab package for neural networks, but I guess you are using sigmoidal activation function for the output units and you are trying to minimize the cross-entropy function. Do you normalize data previously?. You have little # of samples in contrast to #features. Maybe preprocessing with PCA helps. Last, that tests are worse than training could be an indication of overfitting (too many neurons). Try cross validation.

Comment: Yes, I normalize the data. I will try the rest two approaches i.e., PCA and cross validation. Thanks :)

Comment: I tried PCA. Here is the steps I followed:  %%%%%%%%                    %coeffs : nFeatures x nfeatures, scores = nSamples x nFeatures

[coeffs, scores, variances, t2] = princomp(trainData);
testDataMapped = coeffs * testData';
testDataMapped = testDataMapped';

testDataPCA = testDataMapped(:, 1 : THRESH); %%%%
Is this the right way to perform PCA? When I combined all the data and performed PCA, I got infinity values for variance.

Comment: PCA gave slightly lower performance. I tried reducing number of updates while training and got a better accuracy (74 % for training and 64% for testing).